# getElementsByClassName gets one element when it comes from a php foreach

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code in HTML where I have a foreach in PHP so that it generates each div.

I want to change the style of the div class="div-oculto" when I click Ocultar(hide) and Mostrar(show) but only in the div selected.

My problem is when I click on "Ocultar", it hides all the divs from the class "div-oculto", not just the selected one. The same happens when I click on "Mostrar". It shows me all the div class="div-oculto"s, not just the selected one.

I can't use getElementById()because each div is created according to the foreach generated by PHP.

I think I have to add an addEventListener() to my elements but I do not know how to do it so that it works.

Please, help me.

Thank you so, so much!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
  function Mostrar(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('div-oculto');

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.display = 'block';
      }
    }


function Ocultar(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('div-oculto');

  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

</script>
```

```html
<?php foreach ($cursos as $curso) {?>


<div class="contenedor-curso">

  <div class="contenedor-izq">
   
    <div class="duracion-frecuencia-horario">
      <ul>
        <li>Duración</li>
        <li><strong><?php echo $curso->duracion; ?></strong></li>
        <br>
        <li>Horario</li>
        <li><strong><?php echo $curso->horario; ?></strong></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pedirInfo">
      <input type="submit" value="Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar()">
    </div>



  <div class="div-oculto" id="div-oculto">
    <div class="descripcionCurso">
      <p><?php echo $curso->detalle; ?></p>
    </div>

  <div class="pedirInfo">
    <input type="submit" value="Ocultar" onclick="Ocultar()">
   </div>
    
  </div>

<?php } ; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to apply a event listener for each object that you want to click on, but not as a group. You still can use the same handler function for those groups though.
For example:

```
    var ocultoElements = [];
    window.onload = function () {
        ocultoElements = document.getElementsByClassName('div-oculto');
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            ocultoElements[i].addEventListener("click", oculto_clickHandler.bind(this));
        }
    }
    function oculto_clickHandler(e) {
        for (i = 0; i < ocultoElements.length; i++) {
            if (ocultoElements[i] !== e.target) {
                ocultoElements[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                ocultoElements[i].style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would be the easiest approach. You could significantly shorten this code by using `this` to reference each individual item as well.

Comment: Do I have to remove the onclick from the html tag?
<input type="submit" value="Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar()">

I remove it but it does not work for the moment :(

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't use the same name for the class as for the id of a element, as this will lead to confusion (for you). Secondly, if you want just certain div elements to react to a specific button click event then you should target them individually in each of those click event handlers. What I wrote was a generalization approach for what you had presented.